Help with identifying wall material
I'm in an apartment building in New York from the 1930s, looking to hang shelves on an interior wall. It's possible the interior wall is newer than the rest of the building or was rebuilt at some point, though I don't have any specific reason to think it was.
I took some pictures of the area around the wall socket and slid my phone inside the wall to get some pictures there, too.
It seems like the near wall (with the socket, the one I'm focused on) isn't even making contact with the stud in the pictures—the other wall is, but on my side there's a gap. I'm not sure what's keeping it in place.
Photos


My first thought was sound dampening but those usually have insulation still. My other guess would be saving money, but I'm not certain

Is it stiff at the edges.  If it is, then it could cement fibre board.  It used to have asbestos but later they used cellulose fibres.  But isnt your question - how to repair it?

Welcome. Please take the [tour] so you know how to use this site.

This looks like plaster from the transitional period between it and drywall, where traditional wood lath was replaced with various things, such as the Masonite KristoferA mentions or early gypsum panels (a.k.a. "rock lath").
See also Is this plaster over gypsum wallboard?
It appears that your wall finish is mounted on resilient channel, a sound-deadening device which explains the gap. I believe that's what you see reflecting light in the photo. You'll need to read up on mounting over that, as you can damage your wall if you simply tighten screws over the gap.

By the gap I don't just mean that small horizontal white spot in the interior photo--I mean that if I feel behind the wall where the visible stud is, the wall material doesn't make contact with the stud.
Ideally I'd like to find the studs in the wall for hanging heavy shelves. Electronic stud finder is unreliable here, and the magnetic one seems like it's picking up on random items (probably like that random nail in the stud in the interior photo).
Any thoughts on how to do this? I actually thought about buying an endoscope...

That's a different question and should not be asked in a comment here. See many existing questions.

Answer updated.

Okay. Can I ask: wouldn't a resilient channel wall usually have insulation inside? Also, a magnetic stud finder didn't find anything that would indicate a horizontal metal piece.
In the last two photos there is some kind of crossboard against the stud. Could the wall be drywall over older lath and plaster?

I've offered about as much as I can with what I know. You'll need to do more investigation.

Looks like Masonite board to me.

A reference or picture would be useful.
